# how to create Select material UI without using material material UI library

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui

I'm trying to create a Select like material UI but i don't want to use material UI in my project.
I'm trying to achieve that with onfocus to move the label to the top left corner.

```
export default function App({...props}) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        {...props}
      />
      <label>{props.placeholder}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standalone material select

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material/select
```

or you want to build yourself see the working example here

```
https://codepen.io/pavelvaravko/pen/qjojOr
```